# Gorm: Filtering criteria by a property related field

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the following criteria:

```
Alert.createCriteria().add(Restrictions.isNull('resolvedDate'))
```

And I need to filter with a "property's property" field: alert.device.room.id
Something like:

```
Restriction.eq("alert.device.room.id", roomId)
```

How can I add this restriction to the main criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this in much more of a Grails 'way' using the HibernateCriteriaBuilder's DSL:

**Using Nested Closures**

```
Alert.createCriteria().list() {
    isNull('resolvedDate')

    device {
        room {
            idEq(roomId)
        }
    }
}
```

`idEq(roomId)` could be replaced with `eq('id', roomId)` and then used with non-id properties as well.

**Using createAlias**

```
Alert.createCriteria().list() {
    isNull('resolvedDate')

    createAlias('device', 'd')
    createAlias('d.room', 'r')
    eq('r.id', roomId)
}
```

Comment: Excellent! The first approach is what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Very welcome, the second approach has some other benefits (able to use outer joins) but yes, the first approach looks cleaner for your application.